# Algorithm for finding content on an html page

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm wondering if there's an existing technique or library to find content on an html page while scraping it. I'm using both server side and client side javascript, so I could utilize either.

I initially thought of the original readability.js, but that doesn't seem to be available any more. The ideal technique doesn't need to be super accurate, just able to parse some text from the page. Something like how the Facebook scraper works would be perfect.

Comment: Of course, but you wouldn't be able to do it in Javascript because of the same origin policy. You need to use a backend technology and parse HTML with a HTML/DOM/XML parser

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [decruft](http://www.minvolai.com/blog/decruft-arc90s-readability-in-python/), which is a readability clone written in python.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/